# Navigation bar with multiple buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation bar with a left and right button, and I need to put another button next to the right button. Does anyone know how I can go about this? Here is some code to help:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {

        _pinArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
        _pinArray = [Data singleton].annotations;

        UIBarButtonItem *right = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Map"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:self
                                                            action:@selector(goToMap:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = right;

        UIBarButtonItem *left = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Menu"
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                           target:self
                                                           action:@selector(goToMenu:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left;
        self.navigationItem.title = @"My Homes";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's quite easy :)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624956-rightbarbuttonitems

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightA, rightB] // @[rightA, rightB] for ObjC
```

Comment: Actually there isn't a max. You can add as many as you'd like, even to a detriment lol. But really its as many as you can fit comfortably. Think about your users!

Comment: What to do if we want to disable any one of these??

Comment: The easiest way is to hold the individual buttons as properties. Then you can simply set `enabled = false` on each button individually.

Comment: Love when things are this easy

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`, use

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems //note the plural
```

This allows you to set an array of buttons rather than a single one.

See the [UINavigationItem class reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624956-rightbarbuttonitems) for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
  let RightBarButton = UIButton()
        RightBarButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        RightBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(30,0,30,30)
        RightBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "search-icon.png"), forState: .Normal)
        RightBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.OpenQuickLink), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        let RightBarButton2 = UIButton()
        RightBarButton2.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        RightBarButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)
        RightBarButton2.setImage(UIImage(named: "share-icon.png"), forState: .Normal)
        RightBarButton2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BaseViewController.Opensharelink), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let barButtonItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: RightBarButton2)

        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: RightBarButton)


navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButtonItem1, barButtonItem2]
```