# Add rightBarButton to existing rightBarButtonItem in navigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIViewController with a rightbarButton already present in the navBar
I want on certain occasion to add an other rightBarButton to the one already present...

I used the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803609/how-to-add-2-buttons-into-the-uinavigationbar-on-the-right-side-without-ib) but it doesn't work : it adds the new rightbarbutton but removes the first that was present before

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329916/navigation-bar-with-multiple-buttons/)

Basically you need to use the plural form `rightBarButtonItems` instead of the singular `rightBarButtonItem` to create an array of buttons.