# Add UIBarButtonItem in Interface Builder to navigated UIViewController?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationController` in Interface Builder in a storyboard.  I've added two `UIBarButtonItems` to the first `UIViewController`.  They display just fine.  How can I add them to the second `UIViewController` which is navigatated to?  On that view controller, I only see the Back button.

When I try dragging a `UIBarButtonItem` to the top of the second view controller, the button ends up at the bottom of the scene for some reason.  It is not displayed when running the app.

Edit: I should have mentioned that I know how to do this in code, but not in Interface Builder.

[image: Adding UIBarButtonItems in Interface Builder]

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14329962/3633534

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple UIBarButtonItems on right side of Navigation Bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341263/how-to-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-on-right-side-of-navigation-bar)

Comment: Did you drag and drop an Navigation item in the second view controller from interface builder ?

Comment: @Sujay Any idea how to do it in IB instead of code?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo the second view controller has nothing special added to it.  I just created a segue from the button to the second view controller and then tried adding UIBarButtonItems to the space at the top.  Did I miss a step?

Comment: @Slack, Just drag and drop  2 "bar button item' in your navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add further informations about my comments concerning navigation item :

Here is a simple project with a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`. A second `UIViewController`can be pushed via the Next button.
If you select the next button, you can see in the hierarchy that this button is embedded within the group `Right Bar Buttons Items`, which is embedded within the `First` object. In fact, `First` is a `UINavigationItem` automatically added to your view controller when it was embedded in the navigation controller.

[image]

But the second view controller (the pushed one) doesn't have this navigation item since it isn't directly embedded within a navigation controller. Simply drag and drop it from the Object Library to your view controller.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was it.  In summary: adding a second view controller in IB does not include a Navigation Item.  Just drag that onto the second view controller, and then UIBarButtonItems can be placed on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

@Slack, As i said earlier just drag and drop 2 **"bar button item"** in your navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: You can do it in the view controller directly embedded within the navigation controller, but if you add a view controller after this one, you add to manually add the navigation item first.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo- No, I haven't added navigation item. Directly dragged and dropped bar button item in navigation bar

Comment: @Sujay: This works for the root view controller, but if you add a 2nd view controller, it does not contain a navigation item.  Maybe my original question wasn't clear enough. Thanks for thinking about it though.